# Is this patent still valid?

Tags: legal-status, us20070187560a1, us7669818

Is the following patent is still enforceable?

The publication numbers are [US 7,669,818 B2](http://www.google.com/patents/US7669818) and [US 2007/0187560 A1](http://www.google.com/patents/US20070187560).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The links in the question lead to google patents where you can find the link to espacenet. In the legal section you see that the patent got granted and the fees were paid. It doesn't say lapsed or anything like it.

You could find the same information at 'Public Pair' (google it).

The priority date of the patent seems to be 2006, therefore the patent could be valid until 2026 (even longer if there is a patent term adjustment). It can however expire earlier if the owners don't pay the fees. It could get invalidated too. You can find out if such event ocurred at public pair, too.

Comment: Good answer, but it would be even better if you referenced the priority date and the expected expiration date.